# the difference between switch that tests a variable and a switch that tests a statement

Tags: javascript

```js
var age = 16;

switch (true) {
  case age < 16:
    console.log("is a boy, he only drinks juice");
    break;
  case age >= 16 && age <= 20:
    console.log("he can drink beer now ");
    break;
  default:
    console.log("This is not working");
}

var age = 13;

switch (age) {
  case age < 16:
    console.log("is a boy, he only drinks juice");
    break;
  case age >= 16 && age <= 20:
    console.log("he can drink beer now ");
    break;
  default:
    console.log("This is not working");
}
```

why the second switch is not working ? and the first one works and how is it possible to make the second switch work ?

Answer (score 0):

`switch-case` compares equality between the value resulted in the expression and the values defined as cases.

In your first statement the expression is `true` which is the value you want to compare, so the cases should be `case true` and `case false`.
In your code to wrote 'age>=16' etc... These are actually values of true or false, therefore the value in the `switch` can be compared to the `cases`.

In your second statement, you try to compare `age` which is an integer, with cases that are `booleans`, therefore, no case will be hit.

In your case, `switch-case` statement isn't suitable to your propose (you can use `if-else`)